# Create polynomial function

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

In my test I was asked to write a function createPolynomial that
takes as arguments a list of  numbers 0, … , −1 and returns as output a
function. The returned function takes a number 0 and return the value of
the polynomial 0 ⋅ 0 + ⋯ + −1 ⋅ −1 at 0. To this end,  I used the
built-in pl expt function taking two numbers  and , and returning ^

i was given a partial code which I will post down below with my answer and wanted to test my answer at home but I can't make it run although my teacher marked my answer as correct. Any help would be appreciated

here is the partial code:

```
(: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> <-fill in->)
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
 (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
Number)
 (define (poly argsL x power accum)
 (if <-fill in->
 <-fill in->
 <-fill in-> )
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
     (define (polyX x)
     fill in)
     fill in)

And here is my answer:

    (: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> (Number -> Number))
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
 (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
Number)
 (define (poly argsL x power accum)
 (if (null? argsL)
  accum)
 (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power)))))
 (: polyX : Number -> Number)
 (define (polyX x)
 (poly coeffs x 0 0)
 polyX x))

and here are some test for the code:

> (createPolynomial '(1 2 4 2))
- : (Number -> Number)
#<procedure:polyX>
(define p2345 (createPolynomial '(2 3 4 5)))
(test (p2345 0) =>
 (+ (* 2 (expt 0 0)) (* 3 (expt 0 1)) (* 4 (expt 0 2)) (* 5
(expt 0 3))))
(test (p2345 4) =>
 (+ (* 2 (expt 4 0)) (* 3 (expt 4 1)) (* 4 (expt 4 2)) (* 5
(expt 4 3))))
(test (p2345 11) => (+ (* 2 (expt 11 0)) (* 3 (expt 11 1)) (* 4
(expt 11 2)) (* 5 (expt 11 3))))
(define p536 (createPolynomial '(5 3 6)))
(test (p536 11) => (+ (* 5 (expt 11 0)) (* 3 (expt 11 1)) (* 6
(expt 11 2))))
(define p_0 (createPolynomial '()))
(test (p_0 4) => 0)
```

I'm getting the error -

```
define: empty body (after defns/decls) in: (define (createPolynomial coeffs) (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number -> Number) (define (poly argsL x power accum) (if (null? argsL) accum) (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power))))) (: polyX : Number -> Number) (define (polyX x) (poly coeffs x 0 0) polyX x))
>
```

Comment: What are the "−1" things? Is  meant to be the same as  from −1, or is  different? Is it meant to be <sub>−1</sub> with  different  variables, or is it meant to be ^(−1), where there's only one  variable and it's raised to  different powers? Or is it supposed to be a multiplication and subtraction (*) − 1?

Comment: @ Alex Knauth sorry for not making it clear it should be <sub>(−1 ) meaning the X in the n'th place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty means that the there are no expressions in the body.
Usually it means a parenthesis is misplaced.
Use indentation!

I am guessing, you meant to write:

```
(: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> (Number -> Number))
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
  (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number ->
     Number)
  (define (poly argsL x power accum)
    (if (null? argsL)
        accum)
    (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power)))))
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
  (define (polyX x)
    (poly coeffs x 0 0))
  (polyX x))
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer above didn't help me (cus I'm writing in pl)
So this is my solution:

```
(: createPolynomial : (Listof Number) -> (Number -> Number))
(define (createPolynomial coeffs)
  (: poly : (Listof Number) Number Integer Number -> Number)
  (define (poly argsL x power accum)
    (if (null? argsL)
        accum
        (poly (rest argsL) x (+ power 1) (+ accum (* (first argsL) (expt x power)))) ))
  (: polyX : Number -> Number)
  (define (polyX x)
    (poly coeffs x 0 0))
  polyX
  )
```

You call the polyX (that is a Num -> Num) as the return of "createPolynomial".

So when calling (in some define) createPolynomial with a list of numbers then you call again to what you define with a number, that number will go into polyX that will use the list and x to create the poly function.